# S1449 for String.Compare with StringComparison flag

Tags: c#, sonarlint

I have the following code:

`string.Compare(value, expression.MatchValue, StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0;`

This line creates the following SonarLint warning:

S1449: Define the locale to be used in this String operation.

I would assume that, because I specified the `StringComparsion.Ordinal` value, I did specify which local to use, and the S1449 warning should not be raised.

Is this correct? If so, is there any way to create bugs for SonarLint (I created an account at https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS/ but it appears I do not have the privileges to create an account).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been recently fixed in SonarLint: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-782

It will be part of the next release (version 1.8.0) due today or in the upcoming days.